# PowerShell Script to Harvest System Inventory

Tags: beginner, powershell

I've written a 'fast & dirty' PowerShell script to harvest a system inventory of Windows client and\or server operating systems to streamline case note documentation.

```
$NewLine = "`n"
$FileName = Join-Path $Env:USERPROFILE 'Desktop\System Inventory.txt'

# Current Date

$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format F 
$SystemInventory = "# Current Date", $NewLine, $TimeStamp, $NewLine

# Detailed System Information

$OS = systeminfo.exe
$SystemInventory = $SystemInventory + "# Operating System", $OS, $NewLine

# PowerShell 

$PoSh = $PSVersionTable.PSVersion 
$SystemInventory = $SystemInventory + "# PowerShell", $PoSh, $NewLine 

# .Net Framework

function Get-NetFramework {

    $Lookup = @{
        378389 = [version]'4.5'
        378675 = [version]'4.5.1'
        378758 = [version]'4.5.1'
        379893 = [version]'4.5.2'
        393295 = [version]'4.6'
        393297 = [version]'4.6'
        394254 = [version]'4.6.1'
        394271 = [version]'4.6.1'
        394802 = [version]'4.6.2'
        394806 = [version]'4.6.2'
        460798 = [version]'4.7'
        460805 = [version]'4.7'
        461308 = [version]'4.7.1'
        461310 = [version]'4.7.1'
        461808 = [version]'4.7.2'
        461814 = [version]'4.7.2'
        528040 = [version]'4.8'
    }
Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | `
        Get-ItemProperty -Name Version, Release -EA 0 | Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -eq "Full" } | `
            Select-Object @{ Name = ".NET Framework"; expression = { $_.PSChildName } }, Version, Release
}  
$NetFrmWrk = Get-NetFramework | Format-Table -AutoSize
$SystemInventory = $SystemInventory + "# .Net Framework", $NetFrmWrk 

# Storage Capacity

function Get-FreeSpace {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" -Computer . |
        Select-Object SystemName, DeviceID, VolumeName,
        @{ Name = "Total Size (GB)"; expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($_.Size / 1GB) } },
        @{ Name = "Free Space (GB)"; expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($_.Freespace / 1GB) } },
        @{ Name = "Free Space %"; expression = { "{0:N1}" -f (($_.Freespace / $_.Size) * 100) } } | Format-Table -AutoSize
} 
$Storage = Get-FreeSpace 
$SystemInventory = $SystemInventory + "# Storage", $Storage

# WindowsUpdateHistory 
  
$Session = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID('Microsoft.Update.Session'))
$Search = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Count = $Search.GetTotalHistoryCount()
$Patch = $Search.QueryHistory(0, $Count)
$Updates = @()
    
foreach ($Update in $Patch) {
    if ($Update.Operation -eq 1 -and $Update.ResultCode -eq 2 -and $Update.Title -notlike '*KB2267602*'-and $Update.Title -notlike '*KB4052623*') {
        $Updates += New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{            
            'KB'          = [regex]::match($Update.Title, 'KB(\d+)')
            'Date'        = $Update.Date
            'Title'       = $Update.Title
            'Description' = $Update.Description
        }
    } 
} 
$UpdateHistory = $Updates | Sort-Object Date -Descending | Format-Table KB, Date, Title -AutoSize 
$SystemInventory = $SystemInventory + "# Updates & Hotfixes", $UpdateHistory
 
# Roles & Features

$CimOsInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
$CimSysType = $CimOsInfo.ProductType

if ($CimSysType -eq 1) {
    Function ClientFeatures {
        Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object State -EQ 'Enabled' | Select-Object FeatureName | Sort-Object FeatureName
} 
$ClientFeatures = ClientFeatures
$SystemInventory = $SystemInventory + "# Roles & Features - Windows Client Platform", $ClientFeatures
}
else { 
    Function ServerFeatures {
        Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object Installed | Format-Table -Autosize -Wrap
} 
$ServerFeatures = ServerFeatures
$SystemInventory = $SystemInventory + "# Roles & Features - Windows Server Platform", $ServerFeatures    
}

# Save & Display Results

Clear-Host
Write-Host "Hard copy saved as" $FileName; Write-Host
$SystemInventory | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding ascii
Get-Content -Path $FileName
Write-Host "Hard copy saved as" $FileName; Write-Host
```

The results when run against my current system: [System Inventory - Results](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvdD4MxAwWZA4EOvaJC9ey_6KuoE?e=z8bTHT).

I have tested and validated this code's performance against remote systems within an active directory environment a few months back but have made several changes since then. As things stand right now, I currently do not have the resources to validate my code's performance against systems within an Active Directory environment. Real basic, I ran my script using the following sequence:

1. Launch PowerShell (Admin)
2. & '.\System Inventory.ps1' <remote system
   name, e.g. \AUPP-DC01>

Would very much appreciate the community's thoughts relative to this routine's performance and overall utility.

Thank you so much!

Comment: the  1st thing that comes to mind is running all this in parallel. the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet will accept a list of systems & a scriptblock ... and then run it on those systems in parallel. quite a time saver. [*grin*] the other is making all those calls to the target system ... even if you just want to hit one system, don't make multiple calls targeting that system ... send the code to the target & run it there.